# Old version of app not available after new flight was accessed in Microsoft Store

Tags: microsoft-store, microsoft-partner-center

In the Microsoft Partner center, I've created a flight with a new version that needed to be tested. This version could be accessed by a specific microsoft account used by our tester. The tester needed to log in in the Microsoft store with this microsoft account and he can download the new version of the app and test it. Other users keep on getting the old version.
This works....
Then the tester needs to check something on the old (publicly available) version. So the tester uninstalls the app from his system, logs out from the microsoft store thinking he would get the publicly available app. This does not work though! He keeps on getting the flight version.

Basically once logged in the Microsoft store with that test user microsoft account you will never be able on that pc to get the old publicly available app.

Tried Signing out of the Microsoft store, restarting, clearing cache, logging in with another Microsoft account on the Microsoft store ...

What is going on here? Is there a way to get to the publicly available version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked on other systems (on my pc I still had the issue for some reason. If I find out why I will post it here)

If you have uninstalled the app and signed out the test user microsoft account in the microsoft store. Close the microsoft store.

Go to Settings => Accounts/Email & accounts on your system

Under Accounts used by other apps is the test user microsoft account

Remove that one

Just to be sure run wsreset (will remove microsoft store cache and will open it.

Download the app (should be the publicly available app)

**Later Addition**

Figured out why it was not working on my pc.
I've found out that for some reason a package of my application was still on my system although I had uninstalled it.

To see if there is a package still out there use powershell

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where Name -eq "{Your app name}"
```

If there is still a package there (and you know you had installed it, you can remove it using the PackageFullName (which is displayed)

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package '{PackageFullName}' -AllUsers
```

This solved it for me. Before this removal I could not even debug the app in visual studio anymore. Giving a very weird error ( rejecting a request to register from appxbundlemanifest.xml because the manifest is not in the package root. and a prompt to enable deploy in the configuration manager (=> which was on))